# new type of xcode 4.3.2 error in creating a project with date picker or grouped tableview

Tags: xcode, ios5

i have tried xcode 4.3.2 which worked very good.however,when i use few of the settings with a little bit of change, i get an error:
"The document "ViewController.xib" could not be opened. Could not read archive."

for example:
i try to change the tableview settings from 'plain' to 'grouped'  the error is:
"The document "ViewController.xib" could not be opened. Could not read archive."
needless to say the project works without any error when the tableview is plain.
the same exactly is going when i use the datepicker(same error,and also project works good with regular picker view).
Please advise,

domino

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The xcode crashes? it wont compile the project? it fails in linking? it gives a runtime error? is it only in xcode 4.3.2 or you tried older versions?

Comment: Sorry, i am a newbie - the project cannot run. i have 1 red error. "The document "ViewController.xib" could not be opened. Could not read archive." i have tried to do the same before upgraded to 4.3.2 and did not had any problems.

Comment: So you open your project (or create a new one) and it works fine you add a tableview and it is still fine but when you change its style to grouped and hit Run it complains that it can't open the xib (yet still the xib is open in the interface builder window)?!

Comment: exactly.  this is very basic project and there is no error in the code itself.100% sure.(sorry for late response, i was very frustrated and searched everywhere with no answer for 3 days now..)

Comment: If the story is exactly as you say it is, I only can recommend uninstalling xcode using the uninstall script that comes with it, reinstalling it, also making sure there are no file permissions problems...

Comment: also you can try the same thing on another mac and see if this happens there too?!

Comment: or post the project here so that people can replicate the problem ...